# Combined Hebrew and English text on a web site

Tags: html, unicode, html-entities, hebrew

I wish to allow users to enter Hebrew characters, words, and phrases, amongst English text. My first 'inventon' for doing this is to build a table of all the Hebrew characters, somelike the the tables used on [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML_for_the_Hebrew_alphabet), and the something like a WordPress short-code. where the user enters the Latin alphabet representation of Hebrew glyphs, and my code looks these up and replaces them with their HTML entity codes, e.g.

> The Tetragrammaton is written heb:[yhvh], but may never be pronounced.

This is processed into the HTML:

```
<p><span class="hebrew-glyph>&#1497;&#1492;&#1493;&#1492;</span>, but may never be pronounced.</p>
```

Is this a workable solution?

Comment: What is a workable solution depends entirely on your users. Maybe ask on [user experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) instead. Can't you assume your users will have a Hebrew keyboard layout?

Comment: No, most of my users are English, and use Hebrew glyphs for certain esoteric purposes, such as names top invoke angels or demons.

Comment: BTW. This is not a UX issue, but an implementation one. The users will be happy using specially tagged equivalent English letters and a maybe accents etc.

Comment: Well the implementation is easy, eg. your proposed solution can probably be implemented with a regular expression and a lookup table. What you will implement depends 100% on your users. Eg you're assuming your users know a mapping between Latin and Hebrew letters. Otherwise, what do you mean with the question “Is this a workable solution?”

Comment: The solution of which I ask is not how mainly to allow the entering of Hebrew characters by my users, but how to handle them using English equivalents. An onscreen 'keyboard' would also be pretty OK, if it were a touch screen, or the users were all patient.

Comment: And the question of what to use ('keyboard' or 'WordPress short-code' or something else) is not a programming question. That is a UI design question.

Comment: @roeland I am not asking that question, if I haven't yet made that clear enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i understand your problem correctly, then an on-screen keyboard is the only way to go.

As a hebrew speaker, i can tell you there isn't a clear mapping between hebrew and latin letters.

for example, the letters ק and כ can be represented by the letters k, c or q in hebrew, and so it wouldn't be obvious to the user which letter they should use.

The only way around this is to create an on-screen keyboard.